# Django Tastypie not Updating Resource with ManyToManyField

Tags: python, django, tastypie, m2m

Why doesn't my resource with a ManyToManyField update with this PUT request?

```
curl --dump-header - -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X PUT --data '{"uuid":"blah","pass_token":"blah","favorites": ["/api/v1/organizations/1/"]}' http://localhost:8000/api/v1/devices/2/
```

I get this response:

```
HTTP/1.0 400 BAD REQUEST
Date: Wed, 11 Jul 2012 22:21:15 GMT
Server: WSGIServer/0.1 Python/2.7.2
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8

{"favorites": ["\"/api/v1/organizations/1/\" is not a valid value for a primary key."]}
```

Here are my resources:

```
class OrganizationResource(ModelResource):
    parent_org = fields.ForeignKey('self','parent_org',null=True, full=True,blank=True)

    class Meta:
        allowed_methods = ['get',]
        authentication = APIAuthentication()
        fields = ['name','org_type','parent_org']
        filtering = {
            'name': ALL,
            'org_type': ALL,
            'parent_org': ALL_WITH_RELATIONS,
        }
        ordering = ['name',]
        queryset = Organization.objects.all()
        resource_name = 'organizations'

class DeviceResource(ModelResource):
    favorites = fields.ManyToManyField(OrganizationResource,'favorites',null=True,full=True)

    class Meta:
        allowed_methods = ['get','patch','post','put',]
        authentication = APIAuthentication()
        authorization = APIAuthorization()
        fields = ['uuid',]
        filtering = {
            'uuid': ALL,
        }
        queryset = Device.objects.all()
        resource_name = 'devices'
        validation = FormValidation(form_class=DeviceRegistrationForm)
```

A get on the OrganizationResource gives this exchange:

```
curl --dump-header - -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X GET http://localhost:8000/api/v1/organizations/1/

HTTP/1.0 200 OK
Date: Wed, 11 Jul 2012 22:38:30 GMT
Server: WSGIServer/0.1 Python/2.7.2
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8

{"name": "name", "org_type": "org_type", "parent_org": null, "resource_uri": "/api/v1/organizations/1/"}
```

This is very similar to [django tastypie manytomany field POST json error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9413176/django-tastypie-manytomany-field-post-json-error), but I am not using a through attribute on my ManyToMany relationship.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem turned out to be the validation method.  Using FormValidation means that a uri like /api/v1/organizations/1/ won't validate as a ForeignKey for the Django ORM.  Using a custom validation instead fixes the issue.

Many Bothans died to bring us this information.

Comment: Could you show us an example of what kind of validation you use ?

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you set both `ManyToManyField` in `DeviceResource` and `ForiegnKey` in `OrganizationResource` to be `full=True`.

So when doing a PUT Tastypie expects a full object given to it or at the very least a "blank" object with resource_uri for it.

Try sending in object itself with resource_uri specified instead of just the uri i.e.:
`{"resource_uri" : "/api/v1/organizations/1/"}` instead of `"/api/v1/organizations/1/"`

```
curl --dump-header - -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X PUT --data '{"uuid":"blah","pass_token":"blah","favorites": [{"resource_uri" : "/api/v1/organizations/1/"}]}' http://localhost:8000/api/v1/devices/2/
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion.  When I try using the resource_uri key, I get an error.  The interesting part of the stack trace is: {"error_message": "int() argument must be a string or a number, not 'dict'",...  I also removed the full=True part with no joy -- it gave me the same problem as stated in the question.

Comment: It also results in the error if I do both things (use the resource_uri key and delete full=True) at the same time.

Comment: This is a limitation of Tastypie with full=True. See this: https://github.com/toastdriven/django-tastypie/pull/382 and the initial 307 issue. It is being addressed in 0.9.12 but until then you can do your own thing using hydrate_favorites method. Use this for inspiration: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11276099/django-tastypie-manytomany-saving-error

Comment: Good links.  Why won't my approach work if I remove full=True though?

Comment: Not sure without tracing through tastypie code resource.py with a debugger. It could be because you have a recursive relationship on Organization? My suggestion would be to reduce your example to the most basic example where PUT works and build from there. And I assume you removed full from parent_org as well?

Comment: Another thing that you can do is create a Django ORM device instance then do a GET on it to receive its JSON representation and then directly feed it back as a PUT. Tastypie tries to be consistant in this regard as the responses should always match how you need to input the data back in.

Comment: I had not removed the full=True from parent_org -- but I still get the same problem when I do.  I am going to rebuild some of this and will try your "most basic" suggestion.